# jQuery cycle plugin - how to use .live() with its onPagerEvent?

Tags: jquery, bind, live, cycle

I'm inserting elements into the DOM when the onPagerEvent is called. Is there a way to use .live() with this event so that I can access these new elements? Cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

```
$("#slides").cycle({
  ...
  onPagerEvent: show_slide(),
  ...
});

function show_slide() {
  // create new object and add to DOM ... 
  var img = new Image();
  img.className = 'new_image';
  $('psd').html(img);
}

$('.new_image'); //won't work of course!
```

Comment: `   $('.new_image').live('onPagerEvent',function(){   
    
    
    });
 `

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. 'onPagerEvent' isn't a jQuery event. I'm pretty sure it's specific to this cycle plugin.